# Error import from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code that import some lines from another sheet if only the first cell contain "X". The problem is it just applicates for the first lines ( for example: it imports lines 101 & 102 even if it doesn't contain an "X" in the first cell). Can someone detect me the error in the code below?

```
Public Sub refresh()
'
' refresh Macro
'
' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+y
'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lRow As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    ws2.Range("B6:AP" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Scénarios de menace").Select
    Range("B4:Z398").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Analyse de risque").Select
    Range("B6:Z400").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


        ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        ws1.Range("B3:AP" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

        ws2.Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Range("A6:A" & lr1).AutoFilter
        ws2.Activate: ws2.Cells(1, 1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: It imports me the right columns and add others under them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you:

```vb
Public Sub Test()
    Dim intLastCell As Integer
    Dim wsTable1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsTable2 As Worksheet

    'Worksheets
    Set wsTable1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set wsTable2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

    'Check if Autofilter is on
    If wsTable1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        wsTable1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

    'Search for last cell on column 'B'
    intLastCell = wsTable1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    'Apply autofilter
    wsTable1.Range("A1:B" & intLastCell).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"

    'Select and Copy the results
    Range("A1:B" & intLastCell).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Activate the second table and paste the results
    wsTable2.Activate
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Disable autofilter
    wsTable1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Cryxon for your answer. But I found the error. At first I wanted to paste the cells format so it pastes even lines then I filter and repaste. So when I re paste the result after filtering it just crush the first lines and keep the last ones intact. Do you have an idea of how can I just paste cell's format without text.